# Tracking workflow compilation error source from msbuild output

Tags: msbuild, compilation, workflow-foundation

When building a solution on a machine without VS installed, and getting workflow compilation errors I would like to track down the source of the errors, but the msbuild output is not very helpful:

> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Windows Workflow Foundation\v3.0\Workflow.Targets(80,3): error : The type or namespace name 'Foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

An nothing about the file and line even with diagnostic level of verbosity.
However VS manages to find the file and line number.
I don't want to install VS on the machine we're doing builds on.
Is there a way to tell the workflow compiler to report source file names and line numbers for
compilation errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you build it on the command line using MSBuild on a machine in which it builds successfully using Visual Studio, or does it fail there as well?

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Comment: Fails both with and without VS, VS gives the line numbers and filenames tough.

Comment: The proble is not that I cannot find a particular error, but that I have to start VS on other machine to track such errors.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'm not sure. You may have to get one of the MSBuild or Visual Studio team members to chime in. Have you tried the MSDN MSBuild Forum(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/threads)? They are usually monitoring that.